# Failed to create embedded resource in vs 2008 express

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008, webresource.axd

I have extended  asp gridview for giving column filter and I wish to embedded the js file along with this control.

For this i have done

1. Added a quicksearch.js under js folder
2. Marked the file as `Embedded Resource`
3. Added the entry in AssemblyInfo.cs
           [assembly:              System.Web.UI.WebResource("ControlLibrary.js.quicksearch.js",
          "application/x-javascript", 
          PerformSubstitution = true)]
4. Added the fpllowing code in OnInit() of grid

   ```
      base.OnInit(e);
      Type t = this.GetType().BaseType;
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(this, t, "ControlLibrary.js.quicksearch.js");
   ```

But the RegisterClientScriptResourceis giving me an exception

```
Web resource ControlLibrary.js.quicksearch.js' was not found.
```

I tried the above in vs 2008 express edition.

Why i cannot embedded .js file in dll. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you using single quotes around that string if this is c# code?

Comment: @Nyerguds changed. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sorted it out

Instead of type `t` we have to give the assembly where the embedded script is found
Following code solved my issue

```
Type t = typeof(ControlLibrary.HWGridView);
```